# SpringBoot mongodb org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'Method' found for type XYZ

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

**Environment Details**

Spring Boot & Spring Boot Starter MongoDB 2.1.16.RELEASE

Spring Framework 5.1.5.RELEASE

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MongoBaseRepositoryCustom<T, ID extends Serializable> extends MongoRepository<T, ID>{
      boolean exists(ID id);
}
```

```
public interface MyRepository extends MongoBaseRepositoryCustom<MyEntity, String>{
List<MyEntity> findByDataId(String dataId);
}
```

```
@Document(collection="data")
public class MyEntity{
 @Id
 private BigInteger id;

 private String dataId;

 // getters and setters
}
```

```
// some class using the repository methods
@Component
public class MyHelper{
@Inject
private MyRepository
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"repository packages"})
@EntityScan({"entity packages"})
public class SpringBootApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
 // main method
}
```

When I try to run the application I get below exception,

Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property exists found for type MyEntity!

Comment: As I can see you provided String in MongoBaseRepositoryCustom as a key type, but in MyEntity class  id is BigInteger, this is your problem

Comment: I tried that as well, but didn't help.

Comment: I think that was the issue, I had few other repositories with same issue, fixed all of them and that resolved the issue.

Comment: So, it’s good news)